# Find missing number in the transformation 2

Tags: number-property

Can you find the missing number? This number has a single digit.

1 → 3

3 → 5

5 → 4

4 → ?

Good luck!

Comment: This, just like your other puzzle, is well-known and its name is '4 is the magic number' riddle. Please refrain from asking these here.

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't realize it is well known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 4 -> 4 because "four" has four letters.

In the end, everything becomes 4.